# Dividing from labels and printing on other labels

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to divide multiple answers from different labels both of which are in string format.

```
double result = 1 / double.Parse(label114.Text);
label135 =  result.ToString();
```

I've tried that code but it won't work

Comment: What is the error you get ?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are trying to assign the [Label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label(v=vs.110).aspx) itself instead of it's [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs4xb3d(v=vs.110).aspx) property :

```
double result = 1 / double.Parse(label114.Text);
label135.Text = result.ToString();
```